# Number that is a limit point of $[0,5) \cup [7,8] \cup (10,12]$ and consider $\mathbb{R}$ with the lower limit topology

Tags: general-topology

My topology book, Introduction to Topology, states:

> Let $A$ be a subset of a topological space $X$. A point $x$ in $X$ is a limit point of $A$ if every neighborhood of $x$ intersects $A$ in a point other than $x$.
>
> Notice that a limit point $x$ of a set $A$ may or may not lie in the set $A$. Notice also that in every topology, the point $x$ is not a limit point of the set $\{x\}$.

So, if $A=[0,5) \cup [7,8] \cup (10,12]$, limit points would include $0, 7,$ and $12$ as $(12,12+\epsilon)\cap A \ne \emptyset$ for each $\epsilon > 0$. Correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not quite correct.

You are right when you say that $0,7$ and $12$ are limit points, but $12$ is a limit point because

$$(12-\varepsilon,12)\cap A\ne \emptyset$$

for each $\varepsilon >0$ instead of what you wrote.

Plus $5,8$ and $10$ are also limit points.

**Edit**

That was being said with the usual topology of $\mathbb R$.

If you want to consider the lower limit topology, then look up the definition of a neighbourhood in this topology, and you will see that only $0,7$ and $10$ are limit points with this topology.

Comment: Doesn't  $(8,9) \cap A=\emptyset$, meaning 8 is not a limit point of $A$?

Comment: @PHaggerty No, because a neighbourhood of $8$ is of the form $(8-\varepsilon, 8+\varepsilon)$, and $(8-\varepsilon, 8+\varepsilon)\cap A\ne \emptyset$.

Comment: We're in the lower limit topology, so 12,8 and 5 are not limit points of $A$

Comment: @HennoBrandsma You are right, thank you for your commented I edited.